# How do I do tab completion for a directory argument using argparse in cmd2?

Tags: python, argparse, tab-completion, cmd2

I am using [cmd2](https://cmd2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to write an interactive Python application. I use the `@with_argparser` decorator for argument parsing. One of my `do_` action arguments is a directory. I would like tab completion to suggest directories. I know how to set up tab completion in cmd2 by adding a `complete_` member function, but I think that only works for `do_` actions that do not use `@with_argparser`. How would I add tab completion to the following code?

```
class App(Cmd):
    ...
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('directory')
    @with_argparser(parser)
    def do_load_directory(self, args):
        ...
```